# Windows/WinForms: WM_POINTERUPDATE message received several times without any change?

Tags: windows, touch

I wonder, why I receive the WM_POINTERUPDATE message several time, although it is exactly the same message.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  Debug.WriteLine($"{m}");
}
```

As you can see below, the last 4 WM_POINTERUPDATE messages (0x245) before WM_POINTERUP are absolutely the same. Is there a reason for that?

```
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x19b0c8b result=0x0
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x19a0c86 result=0x0
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x1980c80 result=0x0
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x1970c7c result=0x0
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x1970c7c result=0x0
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x1970c7c result=0x0
msg=0x245 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6016000d lparam=0x1970c7c result=0x0
msg=0x247 hwnd=0x6a08d0 wparam=0x6000000d lparam=0x1970c7c result=0x0
```

Comment: That way you can handle long-press/hover events.

Comment: But 0x247 is WM_POINTERUP. So why do I need WM_POINTERUPDATE? As long as there is not WM_POINTERUP, I know, that I long-press/hover.  Or do I miss something here?

Comment: If the focus is stolen by another app, they won't get the event